# Get data from Instagram API from confirmed project

Tags: json, instagram, feed, instagram-api

I have two projects linked to one clientID. Project "A" is in sandbox, the "B" one is confirmed. I was calling feed with this type of URL

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/[userID]/media/recent/?client_id=[clientID]&count=20&access_token=[mySecretToken]
```

The problem is, that with this type of URL I can retrieve data only for project A. For confirmed project B I always get an error

```
{"meta": {"error_type": "APINotFoundError", "code": 400, "error_message": "this user does not exist"}}
```

I'm following the documentation ( https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent ) but this absolutely doesn't work outside the sandbox!

In another part of documentation I have found this:

> For example, if you query the /users/{user-id}/ endpoint and the {user-id} is a sandbox user, then you will get the normal API response; but if the {user-id} is not a sandbox user, you will get a APINotFound error.

That's really useful information, but I really can' find a way, how can I retrieve data from confirmed (live, reviewed) project.

Can plz anyone help how can I do it?

Comment: Just wanting to know more about the issue - for the confirmed project B, did you receive permission from Instagram to use scope `public_content`?

Comment: Should I set somewhere in instagram account public_scope? I tried to use
[link]https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/[userID]/media/recent/?client_id=[clientID]&count=20&access_token=[mySecretToken]&scope=public_content[/link]

but I have the same result

Comment: In Sandbox mode and Live mode, the user should authorize `public_content`. However, in Live mode, you would have requested Instagram to let you use the `public_content` scope. This would have been done on the Permissions page on the Instagram API site.